Spring Integration: test an IntegrationFlow with simulated JMS source
I have an IntegrationFlow receiving messages from a JMS messageDrivenChannelAdapter and I want to make some performance tests on it. I want to create a Jms source in my test so I can control the number and the content of the messages it produces. What is the best way to do this ?
My IntegrationFlow:
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow artemisIntegrationFlow(
        @Qualifier("jmsConnectionFactory") final ConnectionFactory connFactory,
        @Qualifier(TaskExecutorConfig.EXECUTOR_MESSAGE_HANDLER) TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
        final KpiMongoService kpiMongoService) {
    return IntegrationFlow
            .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connFactory)
                    .id(MESSAGE_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .destination(JMS_QUEUE_NAME))
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(ArtemisKpisMessageDto.class))
            .aggregate(aggregatorSpec -> aggregatorSpec
                    .correlationStrategy(msg -> GROUP_MESSAGE_STATIC_CORRELATION_KEY)
                    .releaseStrategy(getReleaseStrategy())
                    .groupTimeout(GROUP_MESSAGE_BUFFERING_MAX_MILLIS)
                    .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                    .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true))
            .handle(handlerToMongo(kpiMongoService))
            .nullChannel();
}

For now, when I run this code, it takes up to 15/20 seconds to save group of about 1800 Kpis (mean size for those are ~160bytes per Kpis, the handle() is just doing a saveAll() into MongoDB) which I feel is very slow.

Your question is not clear.
You definitely can use an EmbeddedActiveMQ broker: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/embedding-activemq.html
Then you create a JmsTemplate in the unit test to produce as many data as you need into that JMS_QUEUE_NAME.
You might see a problem in your aggregate() though. Since it is not clear what exactly is your getReleaseStrategy() since your messages are not grouped either way.

Thank you for the response, EmbeddedActiveMQ looks like what I need for my tests! I'm using the aggregate() as a temporary buffer to accumulate X messages before going to the next step (+ a timeout to release the group even if I don't receive enough message to fill the buffer), but indeed I'm not sure if it's the right (best) way to achieve this.
